# Error 404 on Braintree Sandbox Payment attempt

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, braintree

I'm trying to implement a Braintree Sandbox payment widget on a project based on Laravel 7. I've tried many guides, but I always come out with the same result.
When I try to make a payment, I end up having a 404 error on the post request. Here's the blade code:

```
<form method="post" id="payment-form" action="{{ url('/checkout') }}">
    @csrf
    @method('POST')
    <section>
        <label for="amount">
            <span class="input-label">Amount</span>
            <div class="input-wrapper amount-wrapper">
                <input id="amount" name="amount" type="tel" min="1" placeholder="Amount" value="10">
            </div>
        </label>

        <div class="bt-drop-in-wrapper">
            <div id="bt-dropin"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <input id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" type="hidden" />
    <button class="button" type="submit"><span>Test Transaction</span></button>
</form>
```

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.13.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
    var client_token = "{{ $token }}";
    braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: client_token,
        selector: '#bt-dropin',
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
    if (createErr) {
        console.log('Create Error', createErr);
        return;
    }
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Request Payment Method Error', err);
            return;
          }
          // Add the nonce to the form and submit
          document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
          form.submit();
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

here the routes:

```
Route::get('settings/houses/sponsor/create', function(Request $request){
    //prende dati validazione da services
    $gateway= new Braintree\Gateway([
        'environment' => config('services.braintree.environment'),
        'merchantId' => config('services.braintree.merchantId'),
        'publicKey'=> config('services.braintree.publicKey'),
        'privateKey'=>config('services.braintree.privateKey')
    ]);
    //genera il client token
    $token = $gateway->ClientToken()->generate();
    return view('user.sponsor.create',['token'=>$token]);
});
    //parte back
Route::post('/checkout', function(Request $request){
    $gateway= new Braintree\Gateway([
        'environment' => config('services.braintree.environment'),
        'merchantId' => config('services.braintree.merchantId'),
        'publicKey'=> config('services.braintree.publicKey'),
        'privateKey'=>config('services.braintree.privateKey')
    ]);
    //definisco ammontare e metodo di pagamento
    $amount= $request->amount;
    $nonce= $request->payment_method_nonce;
    
    //crea un oggetto le cui proprietà sono i dati del pagamento
        $result= $gateway->transaction()->sale([
            'amount' => $amount,
            'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
            'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => true
            ]
        ]);
    //se la transazione avviene con sucecsso allora ritorna messaggio di conferma, altrimenti torna indietro con errore.
    if ($result->success) {
        $transaction = $result->transaction;
        return back()->with('success_message', 'Transaction successful. The ID is:'. $transaction->id);
    } else {
        $errorString = "";
        foreach ($result->errors->deepAll() as $error) {
            $errorString .= 'Error: ' . $error->code . ": " . $error->message . "\n";
    }
    return back()->withErrors('An error occurred with the message: '.$result->message);
    }
});
```

At the moment we're running the project on a Localhost via php artisan serve.

Sorry for comments in italian into the code.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Try putting a `dd('')` in the beginning of the route code to see if it is being run at all. If not, it is probably a routing issue and not a Braintree issue.

Comment: I've tried to put it into the post function and it actually doesn't run the dd, I don't understand why it actually takes the amount, the nonce and the token (which are defined in the same function), but doesn't run anything else...

Comment: Where did you put it, in the very top of the handler for `/checkout` route? If so, it means your application is not routing `/checkout` correctly so it is not a Braintree issue. If not, try adding `dd($amount, $nonce);` after those inputs are gotten to see if it gets those inputs from `$request` correctly.